# Extract specific part from URL

Tags: php, url

I have to extract a specific part of an URL.

Example

original URLs

```
http://www.example.com/PARTiNEED/some/other/stuff
http://www.example.com/PARTiNEED
```

in case 1 I need to extract

```
/PARTiNEED/
```

and in case 2 I need to extract the same part but add an additional "/" at the end

```
/PARTiNEED/
```

What I've got right now is this

```
$tempURL = 'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$tempURL = explode('/', $tempURL);
$tempURL = "/" . $tempURL[3] . "/";
```

is there a more convenient way to do this or is this solution fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this part:

```
'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

you can just do:

```
$tempURL = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$tempURL = "/" . $tempURL[1] . "/";
```

Edited index from 0 to 1 as commented.

Comment: Had to change 0 to 1 but it is working like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's normally a good idea to use PHP's built in functions for things like this where possible. In this case, the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) method is designed for parsing URLs.

In your case:

```
// Extract the path from the URL
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

// Separate by forward slashes
$parts = explode('/', $path);

// The part you want is index 1 - the first is an empty string
$result = "/{$parts[1]}/";
```

Comment: Remember, PHP is written in C. C is much faster than PHP. Solutions built in C will always perform better than solutions made in PHP.

Comment: Just to understand your answer correctly:

1.) I need an URL for the variable $e (in your example --- could use "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']" to populate the variable)?
2.) Why is this solution superior to the one from Rui Silva? (both are working fine)

@Chat Tor

the parse_url function is faster because it is a "native" C function?

Comment: I've updated the answer to be a bit clearer - the URL should be in `$url`. This solution probably won't be any faster, it's just simple string manipulation in either case. The advantage of using `parse_url` rather than simply `explode` is that it will work with pretty much any kind of URL - relative, absolute, with or without a query string, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe regex suits your needs better?

```
$tempURL = "http://www.example.com/PARTiNEED/some/other/stuff"; // or $tempURL = "http://www.example.com/PARTiNEED
$pattern = '#(?<=\.com)(.+?)(?=/|$)#';

preg_match($pattern, $tempURL, $match);

$result = $match[0] . "/";
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you proper idea about your requirment.

```
<?php
    $url_array = parse_url("http://www.example.com/PARTiNEED/some/other/stuff");
    $path = $url_array['path'];
    var_dump($path);
?>
```

now you can use string explode function to get your job done.

Comment: Shouldn't this be in a comments section since it's not an answer but advice?

Comment: @BozidarSikanjic what makes you think it is an advice ? any way still made an edit.

Comment: Look above; iainn gave answer (it produces result), you gave clues where to look for. Even tough I like your approach (not to "serve it on the plate" put to show the way) ;)

Comment: @BozidarSikanjic Why do you think stack is the pace where people work for other, it is a place where everyone helps others, and my code only one line is enough to guide him to get his solution .

Answer (score 1):

Here this should solve your problem

```
// check if the var $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is set
if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
  // explode by /
  $tempURL = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  // what you need in in the array $tempURL;
  $WhatUNeed = $tempURL[1];
} else {
  $WhatUNeed = '/';
}
```

Dont worry about the trailing slash, that can be added anytime in your code.

```
$WhatUNeed = $tempURL[1].'/';
```